# Understanding divs

Tags: html, css

I'm struggling to understand divs.

I want to have the 'nav' panel expand vertically as required. The second issue I have is that I can't seem to get padding to work. Any changes I make tend to end up with the 'section' div drop below the 'nav' div.

Please see below jsfiddle and code.

Thanks in advance.

https://jsfiddle.net/s59cwy9s/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="nav">          
       test    
    </div>
    <div id="section">          
        test    
    <br><br><br><br>        
        test        
    <br><br><br><br>        
        test        
    </div>     
</div>

#container
{    
    width: 1156px;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 10px rgb(0,0,0);
    position: relative;
    background-color: transparent; 
    height: auto;        
}

#header 
{
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    padding:5px;    
}

#nav 
{    
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    min-height: 100px;
    min-width: 80px;
    float:left;
    padding: 15px;
    display: inline-block; 
    height: auto;    
}

#section 
{    
    /*float: none;*/
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    /*overflow: auto;*/
    background-color: white;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#section{
    clear:both;
}
```

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s59cwy9s/1/)

[clear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear):both allows floated divs to stop continuing on the same line with the other floated ones, and drop below.

**Update**: https://jsfiddle.net/s59cwy9s/2/

You could fix your issue by giving a margin-right to the #nav

Comment: Ah sorry, I wasn't clear. I want them to be on the same line. The padding doesn't work when they are, for some reason though.

Answer (score 0):

This may be due to the fact that your name bar doesn't span the height of the webpage completely. Try something like height :100% for the navbar. It might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

First I will recommend is using box-sizing attribute
It contains any type of padding or borders within the container's width and height. Find more about it [Here](https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/). So i suggest:

```
*
{
   box-sizing:border-box;
   /* Use browser prefixes if u want support for other browsers */
}
```

Second is add a class to the container which contains elements wit float css attribute like clearfix and add this code:

```
.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
```

or you can just create a div after the container containing elements with float css attribute and clear it.

```
<div class='clear'></div>

.class
{
   clear:both;
}
```

Using float as much as it is useful brings about a problem in layout if not properly used. https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

My Solution:

```
html,body {height:auto; width:100%; background:red; } 
* { box-sizing:border-box; margin:0; padding:0; display:block; position:relative; } 

#container 
{ 
    min-width:800px; 
    height:auto; 
    margin:0 auto; 
    width:100%; 
} 
#nav 
{ 
    float:left; 
    width:30%; 
    padding: 15px; 
    line-height:30px; 
    background-color:#eeeeee; 
    min-height: 100px; 
    min-width: 80px; 
    background:white; 
}

#section 
{ 
    float:left;
    width:70%;
    padding:0 100px; 
    background:yellow;
}
.clearfix:after 
{
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
 }
```

Hope It Helps You. Though i recommend researching more on layouts since there's other layout which will give you less problem than floats.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some help :
https://jsfiddle.net/6ubhyL5k/

Some advices :

- Take time to really understand how the page flow works (float : left/right) so you will then understand how padding and margin work when you have floating div
- Use what you really know and don't improvise :)
- Don't use `br` to make spaces between blocks (margin and padding are what you should use)
- Take a look at how [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/) works and never forget the responsive design